# Booting kernel failed : Invalid argument

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualbox

While trying to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox above windows 10, I get this error after the purple screen.

I downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu from their website. 
It's called : `ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`

VirtualBox parameters:

```
Type: Linux
Version: Ubuntu 64
Memory size: 2048MB
Create new virtual disk
VDI
Dynamically allocated
File location and size: 2.25 GB
```

[image]

Comment: That file allocation is too small, please make it at least `8 - 10GB`, and please take a shot of the device (not when running) as much as possible extending the Virtualbox app so I can see most of the settings...

Comment: @George It's not working, I set it to 11GB but no change

Comment: Please add the answer second portion of my comment.

Comment: see this : https://askubuntu.com/a/934569/147494

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. My VMware version was 12. So I checked Md5 checksum of my ISO file. But They were different. I found that the ISO file was not downloaded perfectly and a problem happened. So I tried downloading again. Then installation was completed finally.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem, trying to install on VMware and on VirtualBox. I tried setting the RAM up to 4GB and Storage up to 100GB but still no go.
The resolution I was able to reach was downloading and installing Ubuntu 14.04.05 without a problem, then upgrading once the install was complete.