# Booting kernel failed : Invalid argument

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, usb-drive

i try install a ubuntu **ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd6**4 , but with start this say error

Test on VM and BootingPendrive

Comment: the same for me on an old PC.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the ISO you've downloaded is incomplete.

Install [`zsync`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ZsyncCdImage) and go to [cdimage.ubuntu.com](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com), choose a version and copy the `.zsync` link.

`cd` into the directory where your downloaded ISO previously.
Run zsync to update the image.

```
$ zsync ZSYNC_LINK
```

Wait until it updates the image.
After processing, it will print something like:

```
verifying download...checksum matches OK
used 1619443712 local, fetched 1594282
```

Try with the updated ISO again.